# Removing white reflective pixels from scanned RGB image (Python - preferably OpenCV)

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, denoising, white-noise

[image: Scanned Painting Tile]
[image: Scanned Painting Tile]
[image]

The images above are tiles taken from a scanned painting. It's easy to see where there are tiny reflections scattered throughout.  I wish to remove (or diminish) the tiny reflections somehow, across a few thousand (50k) such images. I want to preserve as much of the remaining detail as possible.

I am more concerned with the point-like specks than I am the cracks.

I thought that de-speckling may work, but that seems to do something different.

Comment: Will a MATLAB code be helpful?

Comment: @Royi, it might be.. I don't speak MATLAB - but it cannot be that much harder than the 30 other languages I know.

Comment: A median filter of suitable size perhaps? And masking it to only affect really bright pixels?

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could come to.  Improvements are extremely welcome.

```
fn = 'tiles/xxx.jpg'  # set tile filename
img = cv2.imread(fn)  # read tile into img.
# median blur. This seems to be better than gaussian for bright dots.
blr = cv2.medianBlur(img, 15)
# now grab brightness V of HSV here - but Gray is possibly as good
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
val = hsv[:, :, 2]
# use ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN to find spots. 
# I manually tweaked the values- these seem to work well with what I have.
at = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(np.array(255 - val), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 17)
# Now invert the threshold, and run another for edges.
ia = np.array(255 - at)  # inversion of adaptiveThreshold of the value.
iv = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(ia, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 5, 9)
# ib = merged edges with the dots (as an invert mask).
ib = cv2.subtract(iv, ia)
# Turn this to a 3 channel mask.
bz = cv2.merge([ib, ib, ib])
# Use the blur where the mask is, otherwise use the image.
dsy = np.where(bz == (0, 0, 0), blr, img)
result = dsy
```

[image: Tile 1]
[image: Tile 2]
[image: Tile 3]

Comment: Very good! Do you improved this code??

Comment: I used the code written here.  The results were very satisfactory.

Comment: Amazing, actually you saved my life... =)
I just asked...